# Work-energy theorem or conservation of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, work, collision

I am working on a final lab project, and I have collected and analyzed data involving multiple trials of 2 similar mass golf balls colliding and proved conservation of momentum, but I now need to apply either the work-energy theorem or conservation of energy, and I am struggling to figure out which one I should use. I did the work-energy theorem calculations for one trial and got a negative change in kinetic energy so it would be inelastic, but do I need to make a free body diagram and account for all external forces if using this theorem? Or is solving for the external work done from the change in kinetic energy enough? Should I do another experiment set up? I’m sorry for all the questions I am just a tired college student trying to finish a big project the day before finals begin. I can provide more details if needed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have done the experiment with the golf balls moving in the horizontal plane and you have shown that linear momentum is conserved in that plane you can assume that there are no external forces on the two golf ball system.

So you must have to deal with internal forces, the force on golf ball $1$ due to  golf-ball $2$ due to golf ball $1$, $F_{12}$ and the equal magnitude and opposite direction force on golf-ball $2$ due to golf ball $1$, $F_{21}$.

The work done on golf ball $1$, $\displaystyle \int_{\rm collision} F_{\rm 12}ds_{\rm 1}$, where $s_1$ is the displacement of golf ball $1$, is equal to the charge in kinetic energy of golf ball $1$ and there is an equivalent equation for golf ball $2$.

In your experiment you probably found that the sum of the changes in kinetic energies of the two golf balls in not zero, ie the collision is not elastic but to evaluating the integral you need a contact force against position graph for each of the golf balls which might be very difficult for you to obtain.